# Gap between internal cartridge headset and fork

Tags: fork, headset, bearings

so I've replaced the bottom headset on my 2016 Kona Jake the Snake as the old one was rough and rusted. The replacement is the same size in all dimensions however doesn't seem to fit in properly - between the fork and the bottom of the frame there's a sizeable gap. There's no movement in the headset, it's just got about 5mm of space.

The headset purchased is the following: https://www.evanscycles.com/pro-headset-replacement-bearing-outer-52-inner-40-height-7-mm-EV204261

[image: headset gap]

This photo shows that gap, I estimate it to be around 5mm.

[image: gap]

this photo shows how it was before tightened the compression screw on the top. I noticed it wasn't quite right so tried to remove it - but it's now jammed into the frame. Comparing the old headset's fit onto the fork, it sits in a very similar way, albeit with a very slightly smaller gap.

[image: stock image]

This image shows the factory photos of the bike - the gap is visible, which makes me think it's always been like this. There's no crown race on the bottom of the fork, only the taper.

I guess my question is threefold - firstly is there anything that can be done to fix this? the second is, is this safe to ride like this? It seems it's been close to this from factory and the replacement headset is identical to the old one (both are cartridges btw!) The final question is - if it isn't sad for fixable - how does one go about removing a wedged headset cartridge from the frame without mangling it?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Some forks have an integrated crown race, and yours is one of them. 
[image]

When you get a new headset for use with such a fork, you leave the crown race out.

Some sources imply the existence of 36° integrated crown races, but all the ones I've ever seen are the common IS 45°. As long as you've chosen a non-weird headset, it should just work.

Do not ride it like you have it pictured. The crown race that's jammed against your fork could damage it. (It probably wouldn't, but don't risk it.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is the crown race the inner part of the headset cartridge? It came as a 1-piece unit

Comment: For reference - this is the new bearing I fitted: https://www.evanscycles.com/pro-headset-replacement-bearing-outer-52-inner-40-height-7-mm-EV204261 . I've edited the question to include it.

Comment: @tomandco The crown race is the contact point on the fork for the lower headset bearing. It's the silver thing in the picture. Using the one from the box is redundant and won't fit because your fork has one built in.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand, sorry. There wasn't one in the box. All that came was the cartridge bearing which is what's visible in the picture

Comment: @tomandco The silver part that's touching the fork is the crown race, it's not part of the bearing. It might be a little stuck to it but it should come right off.

Comment: I've just added a photo of the bearing - is that inner ring the crown race? Apologies for the confusion, this is my first headset replacement

Comment: If one is present it will look something like: https://cdn.bike24.net/i/mb/ff/ff/04/157910-00-d-281538.jpg . Perhaps I'm mistaken and the entire thing poking out the bottom of the cup is the bearing. That would be very unusual; usually the bearing recesses slightly inside the cup.

Comment: The inner part of the bearing looks just like that - if removed I can see the balls themselves. I'll remove it and test it (carefully!). Thanks once again

Comment: Don't remove it, that's the inner race of the bearing. Something else is going on.

Comment: Hmm ok. I wonder if the replacement bearing is just the wrong size and I need to get my LBS to check it and source a different one

Comment: Does the bearing clearly match the inner diameter of the cup, or is there a gap with it?

Comment: Yep - fits fine.